# Unable to click submit button on form in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, angular9

I currently deployed a website with a contact form. When hitting submit to submit the form, completed or not, there is no reaction to me trying to press the submit button on the mobile version of the website. Most mobile browsers have the same problem. Here is the html page with the form.

```
<div class = "contact">
<div class = "emailBox">
    <div class = "emailBoxForm">
        <form (submit) = "onSubmit()">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <p>Lets get in touch. I'm open for hire and collaboration.</p>
            <ul id = "listForm">
                <li id = "inputForm"><input id = "form_field" type ="text"  required minlength="3" placeholder="Name" #name = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "content.subject" name = "content.subject" /></li>
                <li id = "inputForm"><input id = "form_field" type ="text" placeholder="Email"  required minlength="4" #email = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "content.email" name = "content.email"/></li>
                <li id = "inputForm"><textarea id = "form_field" type ="text" placeholder="Message"  required minlength="4" #message = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "content.message" name = "content.message"></textarea></li>
                <li id = "inputForm"><button type ="submit" id = "subButton">Submit</button></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class = "feedBack">
        <div *ngFor="let needed of missing" style="color: red">
            <ul id = "feed">
                <li>{{needed}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="feedBack" style = "color: green"><h3 id = "feed">Email Sent, Thank you.</h3></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

To add, I have downloaded an android app called "JIDE", to show any log errors on the mobile browser. Even when using "JIDE",nothing happens, its as if I was not touching the button at all.
FireFox is the only browser on my Android phone that works properly.
Here is a link to the website, currently working on certificate.
http://anthonyrodriguez.me/

Comment: this happens only on mobile or is it happening in chrome development tool's mobile view too?

Comment: may be try removing the styles for the button.it looks like your button is not clickable in mobile view.

Comment: Only in most mobile browsers. I have removed the css animation from it and its the same result. @HansakaSandaruwan

Answer (score 0):

You need to `(ngSubmit)` event to your form to catch the submit event.
Try using the below code.

```
<form name="emailBoxForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()" novalidate>
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <p>Lets get in touch. I'm open for hire and collaboration.</p>
            <ul id = "listForm">
                <li id = "inputForm"><input id = "form_field" type ="text"  required minlength="3" placeholder="Name" #name = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "content.subject" name = "content.subject" /></li>
                <li id = "inputForm"><input id = "form_field" type ="text" placeholder="Email"  required minlength="4" #email = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "content.email" name = "content.email"/></li>
                <li id = "inputForm"><textarea id = "form_field" type ="text" placeholder="Message"  required minlength="4" #message = "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "content.message" name = "content.message"></textarea></li>
                <li id = "inputForm"><button type ="submit" id = "subButton">Submit</button></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

Comment: Sadly, even with that adjustment, I still have the same issue.